# call a method in a block?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c-blocks

I'm new to ARC. I want to call a method in a complete block, but I get the warning: **Capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle.**. Code:

```
- (void) handlerComplete
{
    //...
}

- (void) loadData
{
    ...
    operation.completeBlock = ^(NSInteger index) {
        [self handlerComplete];
    };
}
```

Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
- (void) loadData
{
    __weak MyClassType *myClass = self;
    operation.completeBlock = ^(NSInteger index) {
        [myClass handlerComplete];
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a weak reference instead:

```
operation.completeBlock = ^(NSInteger index) {
    __weak Foo *bar = self;
    [bar handlerComplete];
};
```

I think this will work, though I haven't verified it.

Comment: I believe that should work, but the __weak (or __unsafe_unretained) variable might need to be declared outside the block.

Comment: Thanks, while I put `__weak Foo *bar = self;` in the block, I get the same warning. When I put it outside the block, it works.