# ARC capturing self... block inside a block and reference being released before execution

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, objective-c-blocks

I have this problem: a block inside a block.

```
  self.createStuff = ^ (NSString *text) {       
        self.post.onCompletion = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                [self doStuff];  // error here
        };
        [self doMoreStuff];  // error here
  };
```

I will have errors in [self doStuff] and on [self doMoreStuff]. The error is **capturing 'self' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle**

Easy you say, just add

```
id mySelf = self;
```

before the first block and use mySelf instead.

Nope. This will not save my problem, simply because mySelf being of kind id will not give me a post property, needed by the second line. So I need to declare it like

```
MyClass *mySelf = self;
```

Making it like:

```
MyClass *mySelf = self;

  self.createStuff = ^ (NSString *text) {       
        mySelf.post.onCompletion = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error){
                [self doStuff];  // error here
        };
        [mySelf doMoreStuff];  
  };
```

OK, you say, now the self.post.onCompletion line and doMoreStuff are not complaining anymore, but we have another self inside onCompletion... because this is a block inside a block. I can repeat the process creating another weak reference like and this will have to be a weak reference to a weak reference

```
MyClass *internalMyself = mySelf;
```

and use

```
   [internalMyself doStuff];
```

this seems to me to be a pretty pathetic way to do this and more, the app hangs when this method runs. Something like the reference is being deallocated before the method executes...

How do I solve this charade?

thanks.

---

note: this is being compiled to iOS 6+

Comment: Well, this is the time when I would just turn off ARC.

Comment: It will be more pathetic to have one class non ARC and zillions others ARC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it able to call a method in a block?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835476/is-it-able-to-call-a-method-in-a-block)

Comment: @H2CO3: It has nothing to do with ARC. The retain cycle also happens in MRC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're pretty close. Just replace your solution

```
MyClass *mySelf = self;

self.createStuff = ^ (NSString *text) {       
     mySelf.post.onCompletion = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
          [self doStuff];  // error here
     };
     [mySelf doMoreStuff];  
};
```

with

```
__weak MyClass *mySelf = self;

self.createStuff = ^ (NSString *text) {       
     mySelf.post.onCompletion = ^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
          [self doStuff];  // error here
     };
     [mySelf doMoreStuff];  
};
```

The problem with the first solution is that `mySelf` isn't designated `weak`, so it's ownership qualifier is implicitly `__strong` ([see LLVM's documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations)). I'm not sure why this quiets the warning in the first block, but designating the reference `__weak` will fully remove the retain cycle.

Comment: is __weak good for iOS 6? This app is being compiled for iOS 6+ only.

Comment: The `__weak` ownership qualifier will work for file compiled using ARC. Because you're already using ARC, it won't make a difference.

Comment: `__weak` will only work for iOS 5+. If you need to support iOS 4 on ARC, you will need to use `__unsafe_unretained`

Comment: What about `[self doStuff]`, shouldn't you call it using the `__weak` self too? As far as I understand, the first `block` retains our weak self, and the weak `self` retains `self` in the second `block`, so that means the first block is retaining `self` too. Am I wrong?