# AFNetworking: setImageWithURLRequest not setting image

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, block

I'm trying to set an image on an `ImageView` using AFNetworking's `setImageWithURLRequest` on a tableViewCell.  If I do not include the `success` and `failure` blocks in the method like so:

```
[cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:nil];
```

Everything works perfectly and the image sets.  Unfortunately I need the blocks.

Here's what I currently have in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if (self.images) { //check if the array of images is set, fetched from a URL

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: [[self.images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"tbUrl"]]];

        [cell.thumbnailImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                NSLog(@"success"); //it always lands here! But nothing happens
        } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                NSLog(@"fail");
        }];

    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h`:

> If a success block is specified, it is the responsibility of the block
>   to set the image of the image view before returning.

In your success block, you need to say:

```
[cell.thumbnailImageView setImage: image]
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that!!

Comment: This results in a compiler warning (`Capturing cell strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle`) ... Do you know what I can do about that?

Comment: there's a lot of discussions in SO about avoiding retain cycles with blocks, but generally a good solution (in iOS 5+) is to declare a "weak" version of the object referenced in the block, and use that in the block. Here, it would look like '_weak CellClass * weakCell = cell...' See discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14667610/arc-capturing-self-block-inside-a-block-and-reference-being-released-before-e/